# Joystick support in GameMaker game for android

Tags: android, keycode, joystick, game-maker

Does GameMaker support or is compatible to any joystick connected to an android device?
If so is there any tutorial or documentation for implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes indeed! Your options are:

> Android export supports NYKO controllers and generic Bluetooth controllers (including the OUYA), but only when they are enabled, meaning that you will have to tick the iCade/Bluetooth option in the Android Tab of the Global Game Settings. They require API level 12 for them to work fully and it should be noted that GameMaker: Studio will register as connected any Bluetooth devices that your device is paired with, whether or not it’s actually connected. Therefore this should be taken into account when assigning and checking "slots".

A starting point for full controller documentation can be found here:

http://docs.yoyogames.com/source/dadiospice/002_reference/mouse,%20keyboard%20and%20other%20controls/gamepad%20input/index.html